# Hive - rlike not returning results meeting multiple conditions

Tags: hadoop, hive, i2b2

I'm looking to return encounters later than 12-17-2020 for each patient involving any of the antibiotics. I'm expecting many results, as querying by one antibiotic at a time shows me. But when I string them together in rlike, it only returns results for one patient for the first antibiotic, amikacin. Is there something wrong in the syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE tsri.antibiotics AS
        SELECT * FROM observation_fact_meds
        WHERE start_date > "2020-12-17"
        AND encounter_num in (select distinct encounter_num from visit_dimension where patient_num in ('000000', '000001', '000002', '000003', '000004', '000006', '000007') and INOUT_CD in ('Inpatient'))
        AND DESCRIPTION rlike ('amikacin| amoxicillin| amoxicillin-clavulanate| Amphotericin B| ampicillin| ampicillin-sulbactam | azithromycin| aztreonam| bacitracin| cefazolin | efepime | cefiderocol| cefotaxime | cefoxitin| ceftaroline| ceftazidime | ceftazidime-avibactam| ceftriaxone | cefuroxime | cephalexin| ciprofloxacin| clarithromycin| clindamycin | Cloxacillin| Cotrimoxazole | dapsone| erythromycin| gentamicin| imipenem| imipenem-cilastatin| isoniazid| lefamulin| levofloxacin| linezolid| meropenem| metronidazole| Nafcillin| Nystatin| penicillin| pentamidine| piperacillin-tazobactam| Piperacillin | rifampin | sulfamethoxazole-trimethoprim | TNF Antimicrobial Med| tobramycin| vancomycin')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space before pattern - pls put exact string you are looking for a string seperate them only by pipe.

```
DESCRIPTION rlike ('amikacin|amoxicillin|...
```

Comment: It appears to have worked. Thanks!